# Bloch sphere representation of uncertainty

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, bloch-sphere

If we consider the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) in quantum mechanics, which is a two level representation of a quantum mechanical system, then any state can be represented as $$| \psi \rangle = \cos\left(\theta/2\right)|0 \rangle + e^{i \phi} \sin\left(\theta/2\right) | 1 \rangle.$$ We can show that for any state $| \psi \rangle$, the graphical representation of the [expectation values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Operator) $\langle \hat{S}_z \rangle$, $\langle \hat{S}_x \rangle$ and $\langle \hat{S}_y \rangle$ which are the projections onto the $z,x$ and $y$ axis of the Bloch sphere, respectively. Is there any clear graphical representation for the uncertainty in measurments of $\hat{S}_z, \hat{S}_z$ and $\hat{S}_y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is something, and it holds even for mixed states, not only for pure states.

Take an arbitrary density matrix ${\hat \rho}$ corresponding to a point A = $(a_x, a_y, a_z)$ within the unit Bloch sphere, $|{\vec a}| \le 1$, such that 
$$
{\hat \rho} = \frac{1}{2} \Big( {\hat I} + {\vec a}\cdot {\hat {\vec \sigma}}\Big) 
$$
Since the spin averages along directions $x$, $y$, $z$ are the components $a_x$, $a_y$, $a_z$, 
$$
\langle {\hat \sigma}_i \rangle = a_i\;, \;\;\; i = x,\;y\;,z
$$
the corresponding uncertainties read 
$$
\langle (\Delta {\hat \sigma}_i)^2 \rangle = Tr [({\hat\sigma}_i^2 - \langle {\hat \sigma}_i \rangle^2) {\hat \rho}] = 1 - a_i^2\;, \;\;\; i = x,\;y\;,z
$$
Consider for example $\langle (\Delta {\hat \sigma}_x)^2 \rangle = 1 - a_x^2$. Slice the Bloch sphere with a plane perpendicular to the x-axis and passing through point A. Then the radius of the resulting circular cut is $\sqrt{1-a_x^2} = \sqrt{\langle (\Delta {\hat \sigma}_x)^2 \rangle}$.

For pure states, when $|{\vec a}| =1$ and 
$$
\langle (\Delta {\hat \sigma}_i)^2 \rangle = 1 - a_x^2 = a_y^2 + a_z^2
$$
the circular cut crosses through point A, and $\sqrt{a_y^2 + a_z^2}$ is just the distance from A to the x-axis. Similarly for the other axes. So in general,

> For a pure state $\psi$ the spin uncertainty along any direction ${\vec n}$ is the distance from its representative point A = $(\langle {\hat \sigma}_x \rangle, \langle {\hat \sigma}_y\rangle, \langle {\hat \sigma}_z\rangle)$ on the Bloch sphere to that axis.

Obviously the only direction for which this distance and the corresponding uncertainty is null is the direction of ${\vec a}$ itself.

Comment: Quite interesting answer. Is this well known? Also, do you know if there is a well known generalization of the Bloch sphere which describes $N$ two level systems rather than one?

Comment: Honestly have no idea, not using the Bloch sphere all that much lately, but wouldn't be surprised if it was. As for the N two level systems, of course you always have the N Bloch spheres for the N reduced states, and there should be something in terms of graphs for entanglement (and classical) correlations, but again, I am not very familiar with them.

Comment: @udrv Hi, if you have some time, please see [my post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/328345/force-on-two-level-system-in-standing-wave-electric-field).